# Not able to add a java util collection to JsonObject

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

not able to put a any Java Util object to json object  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json.JSONObject.put(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;)Lorg/json/JSONObject;
while  for below. was using org.json version 20170516

```
 final List<String> usersList = getUserList()
final JSONObject inputData = new JSONObject();
   inputData.put("users", usersList );
```

Similar error was coming while try to put map as well

Comment: Why is it complaining about a Map when you pass a List?

Answer (score 0):

This example show you how to convert Java collections object into JSON.

Try the following:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

final List<String> usersList = getUserList()
Gson gson = new Gson();
String users = gson.toJson(usersList);
```